# Is specializing std::hash for a constrained std::tuple considered undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++20

I know that specializing `std::hash` for a general `std::tuple` is undefined behaviour.

However, what about specializing `std::hash` for a specific tuple?

For example,

```cpp
namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<std::tuple<MyType, float>> {
    size_t operator()(const std::tuple<MyType, float>& t) const {
        // ...
    } 
  };
}
```

Or even `std::tuple<Ts ...>` with some kind of `required is_all_same_as_v<Ts…, MyType>` C++20 constraint that ensures that all types in the tuple are exactly `MyType`.

E.g., this

```cpp
namespace std {
  template<typename... Ts>
    requires (sizeof...(Ts) > 0 && is_all_same_as_v<Ts..., MyType>)
  struct hash<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    size_t operator()(const std::tuple<Ts...>& t) const {
        // ...
    } 
  };
}
```

Is *that* still considered undefined behaviour? If so, why?

Edit: made sure to check the size of the parameter pack is at least 1 to avoid specializing `std::hash<std::tuple<>>` which is absolutely undefined behaviour.

Comment: Should be OK. "**[namespace.std]/2** Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace `std` provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template." `hash<std::tuple<MyType, float>>` pretty clearly depends on `MyType` by any reasonable definition (the standard doesn't seem to formally define this "depends on" relationship; it's probably reasonable to apply rules for dependent names).

Comment: Off the top, I'm not sure whether `required is_all_same_as_v<Ts…, MyType>` would make the template "depend on" `MyType`. Probably yes, as long as adding such a specialization doesn't interfere with finding other specializations that don't mention `MyType`.

Answer (score 8):

The rule, in [[namespace.std]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2) is:

> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace `std` provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

Where a program-defined type, from [[defns.prog.def.type]](https://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/defns.prog.def.type), is:

> non-closure class type or enumeration type that is not part of the C++ standard library and not defined by the implementation, or a closure type of a non-implementation-provided lambda expression, or an instantiation of a program-defined specialization

Your specialization of `std::hash` for `std::tuple<MyType, float>` is fine, since that depends on at least one program-defined type (`MyType`) and otherwise meets the requirement of `std::hash`.

Your other specialization of `std::hash` for `std::tuple<Ts...>` where all the `Ts...` are specifically `MyType` is also fine, for the same reason (as long as your constraint eliminates `std::tuple<>` specifically). That's a program-defined type, too.

It doesn't matter what mechanism you use to create or constrain the specialization, as long as any specialization you do provide depends on at least one program-defined type.

(Note that just providing *some* constraint is insufficient. My previous version of the answer misread your constraint as simply checking that all the types were the same as each other. That's constrained, but would still create a specialization for a type like `std::tuple<std::string, std::string>`, which has no program-defined types in it, so would be undefined behavior).

> If so, why?

The issue here is ultimately coherence. Who is allowed to specialize what, where. If the standard library can provide a specialization, you don't want to clash with it. More broadly, if multiple libraries try to define specializations for common things, it would be particularly helpful if each library only provided specializations for its own types - otherwise if multiple libraries are trying to provide `std::hash<std::tuple<int>>`, that's not going to work out well for anybody.

Comment: thats a very good and very important point that the tuple specialization should ensure that there is at least one element in the tuple!

Comment: One could argue that "the added declaration" is a defect: it's not just that the declaration must mention a program-defined type, but that it must affect the interpretation only of specializations that involve one.