# How to write template hasher for std::pair

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a hasher for `std::pair`. It seems, I'm stucked with error, when compiler doesn't see hasher for underlying type, but I'm not sure. Here is the code:

```
#include <unordered_set>

struct Point
{
    std::pair<int, int> coords;
};

struct PointHasher;

struct Edge
{
    std::pair<Point, Point> pts;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct StdPairHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U>& pair) const
    {
        const auto& first_hash = std::hash<T>()(pair.first); // Error
        return first_hash ^ (std::hash<U>()(pair.second) + 0x9e3779b9 + (first_hash << 6) + (first_hash >> 2));
    }
};

struct EdgeHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const { return StdPairHasher<Point, Point>()(e.pts); }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<Edge, EdgeHasher> s;

    return 0;
}

struct PointHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const Point& point) const { return StdPairHasher<int, int>()(point.coords); }
};
```

The error is in `StdpairHash::operator()()` (also, I'm not sure about arrangement of functions in this single file):

```
1>ConsoleApplication9.cpp(20,46): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>ConsoleApplication9.cpp(20,46):
1>the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
1>  ConsoleApplication9.cpp(27,80):
1>  see reference to class template instantiation 'StdPairHasher<Point,Point>' being compiled
1>  ConsoleApplication9.cpp(18,12):
1>  while compiling class template member function 'size_t StdPairHasher<Point,Point>::operator ()(const std::pair<Point,Point> &) const'
1>      ConsoleApplication9.cpp(27,46):
1>      see the first reference to 'StdPairHasher<Point,Point>::operator ()' in 'EdgeHasher::operator ()'
1>ConsoleApplication9.cpp(20,32): error C2530: 'first_hash': references must be initialized
1>ConsoleApplication9.cpp(21,16): error C3536: 'first_hash': cannot be used before it is initialized
1>ConsoleApplication9.cpp(21,42): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Comment: MSVC is being unhelpful, as usual. Clang says `error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'std::hash<Point>'`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zKoP8Ezhr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `std::pair` you rely on `std::hash`, but don't [specialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered) `std::hash` in `namespace std` for `Point` and `Edge`. Both approaches will work, but you need to use one or the other.

Outside `std`.

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename TH = std::hash<T>, typename UH = std::hash<U>>
struct StdPairHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<T, U>& pair) const
    {
        const auto& first_hash = TH()(pair.first); // Error
        return first_hash ^
               (UH()(pair.second) + 0x9e3779b9 + (first_hash << 6) + (first_hash >> 2));
    }
};

struct PointHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const Point& point) const { return StdPairHasher<int, int>()(point.coords); }
};

struct EdgeHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const Edge& e) const
    {
        return StdPairHasher<Point, Point, PointHasher, PointHasher>()(e.pts);
    }
};
```

Inside std:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto hash_pair(const std::pair<T, U>& pair)
{
    const auto& first_hash = std::hash<T>()(pair.first); // Error
    return first_hash ^
           (std::hash<U>()(pair.second) + 0x9e3779b9 + (first_hash << 6) + (first_hash >> 2));
}

namespace std
{
template <>
struct hash<Point>
{
    size_t operator()(const Point& point) const { return hash_pair(point.coords); }
};

template <>
struct hash<Edge>
{
    size_t operator()(const Edge& edge) const { return hash_pair(edge.pts); }
};
} // namespace std
```

(main follows this code, with `std::unordered_set<Edge, EdgeHasher> s;`  for the inside std case)

See, e.g., comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered) for why there is no specialization already for pair. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74708338) re specializing `std::hash` for `std::pair` for arbitrary types and UB.

Outside the scope of the question, but if I were writing this code, I wouldn't use `std::pair` at all. It doesn't add anything in my opinion; it would be clearer if the code was more direct. Use `struct Point { int x; int y; }` and `struct Edge { Point from; Point to; };`. Then the pair hashing function would become a more general hash combine function, which would be more generally useful :).

Comment: Specializing for `std::pair` like in the 2nd snippet is UB.

Comment: @WeijunZhou my bad, fixed, thank you